# I am trying to count the amount of occurences and spread to multiple columns and want the number to aggregate as time goes on

Tags: r, machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have 3 columns which is Game ID: labeled as Address on the image, the team: red or blue, and Time: 0 to 60 minutes. The Game ID is unique to the game but occurs multiple times in that column. Each row is a recorded kill. My end goal is to have just one Game ID as a row and spread the Time into columns from minute 0 to minute 60 for both the red and the blue team. I want to count each time a kill occurs and put it into the correct column but have it aggregate over the columns for each team. The End Result might have a row with the Game ID, their kills throughout the game aggregated over the time for both the red and blue team. The goal of doing this is to create predictors for our model, we will be creating 60 models for each minute and use the red and blue team kills to get our prediction. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNmnK.png

Comment: Please add details on what you've tried so far. You may take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/3981539) for reference.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.